# Subdomain not being recognised in sites-available

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain

I was wondering what are the common things you should look at when debugging a new subdomain not being picked up correctly by apache.

Here are the steps I followed to create the sub-domain;

I copied the setup file from an existing (working) domain in sites-available.

`sudo cp old new`

Then I edited this to work with the new site (replace 'old' with 'new')

> < VirtualHost *:80>
>
> ServerName new.srv.co.uk
>
> DocumentRoot /srv/www/new/public_html/
>
> ErrorLog /srv/www/new/logs/error.log
>
> CustomLog /srv/www/new/logs/access.log combined
>
> < /VirtualHost>

I then created the link in the sites-enabled folder.

`ls -s ../sites-available/new new`

The next step was to create the appropriate directories in `/srv/www/` and gave them the same permissions as other site already listed there.

Finally I restarted apache

`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

It restarts fine but the URL will not work for the site.

If I edit the file in sites-available to break it (remove the '*' for example) apache fails to restart, so I know it is finding that file OK.

There is nothing in the error log and browsers are reporting things like 'Firefox can't find the server at ...'

Comment: What is the error you see in the browser ? Is there anything relevant in your error log ?

Comment: Sorry if it seems obvious, but does you new subdomain dns point to your server IP ?

Comment: @spud, don't apologise, I am sure it will turn out to be something daft I am doing. I am going to double check that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser is telling you that it cannot reslove the hostname to an address. You need to create a DNS A or CNAME entry that will resolve your new domain to the IP address of the server that is hosting your apache server.

Comment: I have checked and the CNAME record is set and looks fine.  It would have only been done today so could it simply be a propagation issue?

Comment: the address in your error message resolves for me and  I get `Working...`